# How to blur background of header in phonegap?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, blur

I'm developing mobile app using phonegap and jquery mobile. I want to know , how can I blur backgroud of header so that when I scroll the body , the background bluring style of header changes according to the new body element that scrolled to top. For the best examle , you can see the ios7 controlle which does it!
Note that I know about below filters.But when I put it as a background of my header , it just blurs the content of header such as title , and it does nothin to the background! How can I do it?

```
-webkit-filter: blur(10px);
-moz-filter: blur(10px);
-ms-filter: blur(10px); 
-o-filter: blur(10px);
filter: blur(10px);
```

Comment: demo on how to blur a background -- http://codepen.io/aniketpant/pen/DsEve

Comment: That's not what I want. It just blur entire background image, not only the part which is behinds of text.Plus I want some thing which can filter and blur backgroune in scroll , that meens it should'nt be static.

Comment: so you don't want to blur the background then? im not sure if you can blur a background color, but search on SO. you going to need an image background in the header. As for scrolling and bluring at the same time you are going to need to know how many pixels you have scrolled on page and blur accordingly. First find out how to create an on scroll function that records the pixels you scrolled. Plenty of examples on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find the answer to my own question. You have to build two elements , one of them is for real background and one of them is your blurred background which second one is copied of the first one , but it has the blur filter. And in jquery , as for scrolling , you have to scroll your blurred element , whenever your real element is scrolled.And your blurred element is set as a background of header by little styling.
[Have a look at this code pen to see the full example.](http://codepen.io/rikschennink/pen/zvcgx)I just put a summerized code.

main.html :

```
<div class="phone">
<div class="screen">
    <header>
    </header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <!-- content goes here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

main.css :

```
.screen {
    width:319px;
    height:568px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

header {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    height:44px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    z-index:2;
    box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}


.content-blurred {
    margin-top:44px;
    padding:0 1rem;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    -webkit-filter:blur(10px);
    filter:url(#blur-effect);
    opacity:.35;
   z-index: 1;
}

.content-blurred .content {
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}

.content-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    padding:0 1rem;
    z-index:1;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
}

.content-wrapper .content {
    margin-top:44px;
}
```

main.js :

```
var content = document.querySelector('.content');
var duplicate = content.cloneNode(true);
var contentBlurred = document.createElement('div');
contentBlurred.className = 'content-blurred';
contentBlurred.appendChild(duplicate);

var header = document.querySelector('header');
header.appendChild(contentBlurred);

var contentWrapper = document.querySelector('.content-wrapper'),
translation;

contentWrapper.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
  translation = 'translate3d(0,' + (-this.scrollTop + 'px') + ',0)';
  duplicate.style['-webkit-transform'] = translation;
  duplicate.style['-moz-transform'] = translation;
  duplicate.style['transform'] = translation;

  console.log(duplicate);
});

// offset to demo blurring
contentWrapper.scrollTop = 140;
```